# Get Timezone from Google Places api autocomplete

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-places-api

I am trying to get the latitude, longitude and Timezone (India 5.30) from Google Places. The address is filled by autocomplete, and thus getting the latitude and longitude. But iam unable to get the timezone. I am getting the latitude and longitude properly. Can anyone help me to get the timezone. My code is below:

HTML

```
<input id="address" type="text" placeholder="Enter address here" />
    <div>
        <p>Latitude:
            <input type="text" id="latitude" readonly />
        </p>
        <p>Longitude:
            <input type="text" id="longitude" readonly />
        </p>
        <p>Timezone:
            <input type="text" id="timezone" readonly />
        </p>
    </div>
```

SCRIPT

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=API_KEY&amp;libraries=places"></script>
 
<script>
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
function initialize() {
var input = document.getElementById('address');
var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input);
autocomplete.addListener('place_changed', function () {
var place = autocomplete.getPlace();
// place variable will have all the information you are looking for.
 
  document.getElementById("latitude").value = place.geometry['location'].lat();
  document.getElementById("longitude").value = place.geometry['location'].lng();
  });
}
</script>
```

Comment: can anyone help me?

Comment: looks like it might have been changed to `utc_offset_minutes` ? [utc_offset_minutes](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/places-service#PlaceResult.utc_offset_minutes)

Comment: let me check that pls

Comment: i tried changing this "document.getElementById("utc_offset_minutes").value", but its not working

Comment: Yeah i understand. But same result. :(

Comment: In the question i have given the HTML also. Basically when the place or address is selected from the auto complete, it has to generate the latitude, longitude and the timezone (India its 5.30)

Comment: No no, actually i was just trying with utc_offset. I am able to get the latitude and longitude. I am not sure how i can get the timezone. I will update my html

Comment: i update the code in my question. Actually i guess i need to call the timezone() api and then generate the timezone from the latitude and longitude. But i am not sure how to do that. May be still i need to try.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To retreive the timezone from google places autocomplete add the following line to the code

```
  document.getElementById("timezone").value = place.utc_offset_minutes;
```

One can also use `place.utc_offset`

Comment: I already tried this, But not a desired result. Means if i am selecting India from google places address text box, then timezone it should return should be 5.5. Its UTC offset.

Comment: Google standard is in minutes. Why not just divide my 60? When I search India it return 330. divide by 60 gives you the 5.5. You can also investigate Google TimeZone Api.

Comment: If this guy doesn't like minutes, he is definitely not going to like Timezone API because it is in seconds.

Answer (score 0):

You can add this code `autoComplete.setFields(['utc_offset_minutes'])` before autocomplete.addListener(....